# Previous Years Data

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

My table has 2 columns, I want to pass two date parameters ie `StartDate` and `End Date` to my stored procedure.

Suppose I pass it `31-Jan-2014` and `20-Feb-2014`. Between these two dates there are almost three weeks, and I want to show data between the three weeks to the date specified and three years previous to it.

```
Date----------------  Sales(2014)-------- Sales(2013)--------Sales(2012)------ Sales(2011) 
20-Feb-2014           100$                140$               150$               900$
19-Feb-2014           100$                140$               150$               900$
18-Feb-2014           100$                140$               150$               900$
17-Feb-2014           100$                140$               150$               900$
.
.
.
1-Feb-2014           100$                140$               150$               900$
31-Jan-2014          120$                 150$              123$               200$
```

Comment: @ChristosPaisios I think I see `sql-server` tagged in the question.

Comment: I am using sql server 2012>i want query.Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to include the value for the same day of the month in previous years (so it doesn't matter that you're comparing e.g. a Monday to a Sunday)? How do you want to handle leap days existing/not existing in the current/previous years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best way, but this is how i would do it. You did not mention if there would be any aggregation in this query, so if you are running a sum, then this would need to change

```
Select [DATE], Sales(2014) ,
(Select  Sales from dbo.table as t_minus_one_year where Year([DATE]) =  Year(@StartDate) - 1) as Sales(2013),
(Select  Sales from dbo.table as t_minus_two_years where Year([DATE]) =  Year(@StartDate) - 2) as Sales(2012),
(Select  Sales from dbo.table as t_minus_three_years where Year([DATE]) =  Year(@StartDate) - 3) as Sales(2011)
from dbo.table as t2014 where date between @StartDate and @Enddate
```

Comment: Dear its not according to requirement.What i want is to show previous three years data,but all the data of previous three years is between the specified dates.